# Linq intersect with sum

Tags: linq, intersect

I have two collections that I want to intersect, and perform a sum operation on matching elements.

For example the collections are (in pseudo code):

```
col1 = { {"A", 5}, {"B", 3}, {"C", 2} }
col2 = { {"B", 1}, {"C", 8}, {"D", 6} }
```

and the desired result is:

```
intersection = { {"B", 4}, {"C", 10} }
```

I know how to use an `IEqualityComparer` to match the elements on their name, but how to sum the values while doing the intersection?

EDIT:

The starting collections haven't two items with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your input data looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>> firstSequence = ..., secondSequence = ...;
```

If the strings are unique in each sequence (i.e there can be no more than a single {"A", XXX} in either sequence) you can `join` like this:

```
var query = from tuple1 in firstSequence
            join tuple2 in secondSequence on tuple1.Item1 equals tuple2.Item1
            select Tuple.Create(tuple1.Item1, tuple1.Item2 + tuple2.Item2);
```

You might also want to consider using a `group by`, which would be more appropriate if this uniqueness doesn't hold:

```
var query = from tuple in firstSequence.Concat(secondSequence)
            group tuple.Item2 by tuple.Item1 into g
            select Tuple.Create(g.Key, g.Sum());
```

If neither is what you want, please clarify your requirements more precisely.

**EDIT**: After your clarification that these are dictionaries - your existing solution is perfectly fine. Here's another alternative with `join`:

```
var joined = from kvp1 in dict1
             join kvp2 in dict2 on kvp1.Key equals kvp2.Key
             select new { kvp1.Key, Value = kvp1.Value + kvp2.Value };

var result = joined.ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value);
```

or in fluent syntax:

```
var result = dict1.Join(dict2,
                        kvp => kvp.Key,
                        kvp => kvp.Key,
                        (kvp1, kvp2) => new { kvp1.Key, Value = kvp1.Value + kvp2.Value })
                  .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);
```

Comment: I like your solution using join, I didn't realize that it has the same meaning as Intersect. I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

This will give the result, but there are some caveats. It does an union of the two collections and then it groups them by letter. So if, for example, `col1` contained two `A` elements, it would sum them together and, because now they are 2 `A`, it would return them.

```
var col1 = new[] { new { L = "A", N = 5 }, new { L = "B", N = 3 }, new { L = "C", N = 2 } };
var col2 = new[] { new { L = "B", N = 1 }, new { L = "C", N = 8 }, new { L = "D", N = 6 } };

var res = col1.Concat(col2)
              .GroupBy(p => p.L)
              .Where(p => p.Count() > 1)
              .Select(p => new { L = p.Key, N = p.Sum(q => q.N) })
              .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

The best I came up with until now is (my collections are actually `Dictionary<string, int>` instances):

```
var intersectingKeys = col1.Keys.Intersect(col2.Keys);
var intersection = intersectingKeys
    .ToDictionary(key => key, key => col1[key] + col2[key]);
```

I'm not sure if it will perform well, at least is it readable.

Answer (score 0):

If your intersection algorithm will result in anonymous type, i.e. `...Select(new { Key = key, Value = value})` then you can easily sum it

```
result.Sum(e => e.Value);
```

If you want to sum the "while" doing the intersection, add the value to the accumulator value when adding to the result set.

Comment: I wanted to use the Linq 'Intersect' operator, maybe not the best idea. I don't see exactly how I can apply your idea.

Comment: you will call `Intersect`, `Select` and `Sum` in one "line": `col1.Intersect(col2).Select(new { Key = key, Value = value}).Sum(e => e.Value);`. And when the items are implementing IEquatable<> interface (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx), there's no problem.